# Can't find the cause of a SyntaxError in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm currently trying to plot an integral equation in Python. It suposed to give the of the functions for three different values of parameter gama. There is gama depedency of the parameter beta and in the wave function itself. Here is the code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.constants import alpha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Constants
epsilon = 13.1 #dielectric constant of the material
gamma_C = 0.5 # donor impurity linewidth 
nr = 3.2 #refractive index of semiconductor
flux = 0.0 # Phi in eqn 8 magnetic flux
R = 5.0  #radius of the quantum ring in nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)
rho = r / R
m_0 = 0.0067*0.511 # electron effective mass
h = 4.13e-15  # Planck constant in eV
hbar =  6.58e-16  # reduced Planck constant in eV
#Photon energy
hnu = np.linspace(0, 100) #in eV

#Function that calculates the integrand
def func(rho, theta):
    betai = gama**2/2
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    return (R *(gama * rho)**(betai + betaf) *
            np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) *
          (gama*rho)**2/2  )

def cross_section(hnu, gama):
    #function that calculates the photoionisation cross section
    betai = gama**2/2
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    Ei = gama**2*(1+betai)-gama**4/2
    Ef = gama**2*(3+betaf)-gama**4/2
    delta = hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2    
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs( np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(1/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 2)) *
            quad(func, 0, np.infty) [0] * delta))

#Plot
plt.figure();plt.clf()

for gama in [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]:
    plt.plot(hnu, (cross_section(hnu, gama))
plt.legend(['$\gamma = 1.0$', '$\gamma = 1.5$', '$\gamma = 2.0$'] )
plt.ylabel('Photoionization cross\n section $\sigma (10^{-14}cm^{2}$)')
plt.xlabel('Photon energy $h\\nu (meV)$ ')
```

But I'm getting a unexpected syntax error on a line of the code:

```
    runfile('/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python/crosssection.py', wdir='/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python')
  File "/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python/crosssection.py", line 49
    plt.figure();plt.clf()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The parentheses don't match in the `return` line at the end of `cross_section()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your bracket at return of the Cross_section
I've run it and got another error XD

```
func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'theta'
```

, at least the Syntax error are known and resolve
here is your edited code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.constants import alpha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Constants
epsilon = 13.1 #dielectric constant of the material
gamma_C = 0.5 # donor impurity linewidth 
nr = 3.2 #refractive index of semiconductor
flux = 0.0 # Phi in eqn 8 magnetic flux
R = 5.0  #radius of the quantum ring in nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)
rho = r / R
m_0 = 0.0067*0.511 # electron effective mass
h = 4.13e-15  # Planck constant in eV
hbar =  6.58e-16  # reduced Planck constant in eV
#Photon energy
hnu = np.linspace(0, 100) #in eV

#Function that calculates the integrand
def func(rho, theta):
    betai = gama**2/2
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    return (R *(gama * rho)**(betai + betaf) *
            np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) *
          (gama*rho)**2/2  )

def cross_section(hnu, gama):
    #function that calculates the photoionisation cross section
    betai = gama**2/2
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    Ei = gama**2*(1+betai)-gama**4/2
    Ef = gama**2*(3+betaf)-gama**4/2
    delta = hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2    
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs( np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(1/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 2)) *
            quad(func, 0, np.infty) [0] * delta)))
#Plot
plt.figure()
plt.clf()

for gama in [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]:
    plt.plot(hnu, (cross_section(hnu, gama)))
plt.legend(['$\gamma = 1.0$', '$\gamma = 1.5$', '$\gamma = 2.0$'] )
plt.ylabel('Photoionization cross\n section $\sigma (10^{-14}cm^{2}$)')
plt.xlabel('Photon energy $h\\nu (meV)$ ')
```

Comment: Thanks! There is an extra argument in the function. I'll handle that